# Destructor in C?

Tags: c++, c, destructor

C++ have nice feature allowing to call some code at end of the block - destructor. Yesterday i randomly discovered trick which in C works similarly like destructor in C++. For illustration, here is usage of this trick to automatically close file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AUTO_FILE( id, name, access ) \
for ( FILE* id = fopen( name, access ); id != NULL; fclose( id ), id = NULL )

int main()
{
    AUTO_FILE( f, "hello.txt", "w" ) {
        fprintf( f, "Hello World!" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this is nice and can have interesting usages. For example if you combine it with stack data structure you can directly in source code declare very intuitive and readable tree structures:

```
frame("frm") {
    menu("mnu") {
        popupmenu("file", "File") {
            menuitem("exit", "Exit");
        }
        popupmenu("help", "Help") {
            menuitem("about", "About...");
        }
    }
    label("lbl", "Hello World!");
    button("btn", "Push me!", btn_onclick);
}
```

But of course this hack don't work like true destructor. If you use `break` or `return` statement inside the block, `fclose` will not be called. But instead you can use `continue` statement if you need break the block like with `break` statement in C++. :-) So maybe this trick can be improved with some macro magic to work almost like true destructor.

So question is:

Is it possible to have destructor in standard C programming language?

Comment: The main question would be "why" since if you want to see what's being done explicitly, you use C, when you want all sorts of magic to happen on all the possible ways to leave a scope you use C++.

Comment: you could probably hack "shutdown function" support into your compiler or underlying standard libraries, but that's not really "c". that's making it "my personal version of C".

Comment: I don't think what you did is quite a destructor, it is more of a construct, if you really wanted what you need, just use a try ... catch and put the close after. To be frank, you are just better avoiding hiding the code with such constructs IMHO.

Comment: You can use hacks like the one above, but I'd generally consider this an antipattern as it would be very, very fragile. It would be better to stick with the tried-and-true methods of C, and if you want more features, switch to the higher level language. This question is likely to be closed as opinion based/too broad though :-/

Comment: No no, there is no destructor in C, and please, do not rewrite C using the preprocessor.

Comment: Technically, since C++ was originally just a pre-processor for C, it's most likely possible to implement everything available in C++ through some regular C concepts. But not necessarily easy, and you will most likely end up having to write your own "C+- to C" translator. Not just using macros. And in that case, you are probably better off using one of the already existing compilers, such as Clang++ or g++, that does the full C++ supprt, rather than some hacked version that isn't quite C++, and not plain C either.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - "... would be better to stick with the tried-and-true methods of C..." : elaborating on these triedandtrue methods for scope cleanup might make a good answer!

Comment: It's usually done with `do {...} while (0);`.